# Android emulator reports 0x501 error while using GPU Emulation with OpenGL ES

Tags: android-emulator, apk, gpu, intel-haxm

I am trying to run the **ArcGIS for Android** samples in Android Emulator. Based on the [ArcGIS recommendation](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/02/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-v1-1-supports-android-emulator/), I have installed the **Intel HAXM** and enabled the **GPU Emulation** as well.

While running the application with Emulator it reports the below console output. It seems the application has been **installed with ERRORS**, but I can see the application layout **without MAP** and its not responding to me.

Please suggest me, is it anything related to insufficient hardware or am I missing any software configuration things to get it worked?

Thanks in advance!

```
[2012-08-17 12:07:02 - GeometryEditor] ------------------------------
[2012-08-17 12:07:02 - GeometryEditor] Android Launch!
[2012-08-17 12:07:02 - GeometryEditor] adb is running normally.
[2012-08-17 12:07:02 - GeometryEditor] Performing com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.geometryeditor.GeometryEditor activity launch
[2012-08-17 12:07:02 - GeometryEditor] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD-4.0.3' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-08-17 12:07:02 - GeometryEditor] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD-4.0.3'
[2012-08-17 12:07:07 - Emulator] creating window 23 23 428 713
[2012-08-17 12:07:07 - GeometryEditor] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-08-17 12:07:07 - GeometryEditor] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-08-17 12:08:32 - GeometryEditor] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-17 12:08:32 - GeometryEditor] Uploading GeometryEditor.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-08-17 12:09:20 - GeometryEditor] Installing GeometryEditor.apk...
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetAttribLocation:825 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:09:42 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glGetUniformLocation:1380 error 0x501
.................
.................
.................
[2012-08-17 12:10:01 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:10:01 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:10:01 - Emulator] sdk/emulator/opengl/host/libs/Translator/GLES_V2/GLESv2Imp.cpp:glUseProgram:1911 error 0x501
[2012-08-17 12:10:27 - GeometryEditor] Success!
[2012-08-17 12:10:27 - GeometryEditor] Starting activity com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.geometryeditor.GeometryEditor on device emulator-5554
[2012-08-17 12:10:30 - GeometryEditor] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.esri.arcgis.android.samples.geometryeditor/.GeometryEditor }
```

Comment: What is your host operating system? Can you confirm that OpenGL 2.1 applications run correctly on your host?

Comment: I am using Windows-7 OS and OpenGL apps are running correctly in my machine.

Comment: Do other OpenGL apps run correctly in the emulator? Is this the only one that doesn't work?

Comment: This post was [crossposted from SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002000/installing-apk-in-android-emulator-reports-0x501-error-while-using-gpu-emulatio). While sometimes it might be valid to have *similar* question on different sites, the question still need to be focused on the topic of the site. As hinted by the answer in SO, it's probably more related to development issue and thus, it's off-topic here.